# Write message to validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-validators

I have a Razor Pages application (ASP.NET Core).

Is there a way to write a message to the validation summary from JavaScript? And have it appear formatted (red, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

The validation summary tag helper adds a CSS class to the div where the validation summary is rendered: `validation-summary-errors`. You can use that (or any other selector you add to the div) to get a reference to the div in JavaScript:

```
var summary = document.querySelector('.validation-summary-errors');
summary.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;'>Oops!</p>";
```